# Why is using StreamWriter.WriteLine, followed by StreamWriter.BaseStream.WriteByte unreliable?

Tags: c#, networking

I am developing a **networking** application.

For sending and receiving data, I am using `NetworkStream` that I get from `TcpClient`.

For sending text, I wrapped `NetworkStream` in a `StreamWriter`, and I simply call `StreamWriter.WriteLine(text)`, followed by `StreamWriter.Flush()`.

For sending 1 byte flags from server to client (that are required for in my own communication protocol), I am using `StreamWriter.BaseStream.WriteByte(byte)`. So, it is all the same underlying stream and it worked great until I got into this situation. The following code is where it breaks:

```
        // This is server sending data to client.
        writer.WriteLine(text);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.BaseStream.WriteByte(flag);

        // This is client trying to read incoming data from server.
        string text = reader.ReadLine(); // This will read text successfully.
        int flag = reader.BaseStream.ReadByte(); // Problem is here: It will block here as if there is no data.
```

---

However, if I put some delay between flushing data and sending the byte, everything works fine...

```
        // This is server sending data to client.
        writer.WriteLine(text);
        writer.Flush();
        Thread.Sleep(1000); <-------------------------------- delay
        writer.BaseStream.WriteByte(flag);

        // This is client trying to read incoming data from server.
        string text = reader.ReadLine(); // This will read text successfully.
        int flag = reader.BaseStream.ReadByte(); // Now the byte is read successfully as well.
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: I think it has to do with caching. `reader.ReadLine()` will read a bunch of data from the stream, return just the first line to you and hold onto the rest in anticipation of the next call. That means subsequent reads from the base stream won't have that read-ahead data available any longer. It needs to be accessed through the reader instead.

Comment: @itsme86 Okay, that makes sense. However, is there a way to just read the line and leave the rest of the data?

Comment: @FICHEKK Send the length first, and then send a byte array instead of a string.  Then read the length and read that many bytes.

Comment: You can wipe the buffer, using the [StreamReader.DiscardBufferedData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata) method, so the the buffer won't hold invalid data. Read the notes about this method, though. Also, the notes left in the [.Net Source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,309)

Comment: The issue is reading not writing.The reading code has to know where the end of each message occurs before you process the receive data.You either wait to you get the end character(a return) before processing;or you add a byte count to beginning of the message.Then receive until you get the byte count before processing.  You cannot process partial message.if you attempt to process a partial message you will get errors. Adding a wait in the Write code just makes sure the entire message is received before processing take place on the receive end.It is not a good solution for high speed transfers.